# Textview android:scrollHorizontally restarting on configuration change

Tags: java, android, textview, autoscroll

I have the following Textview:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detailsText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text Long text "
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

The text is automatically scrolling from right to left (which is what I'm looking for) but after a configuration change the text restart scrolling from the beginning. I have tried to use `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"` and handle the configuration change in my code but this is not working. I also find out that this technique is not advised anymore, and tried to use Fragments instead, but nothing is working. I tried also to find out which value scrollHorizontally is modifying to do it's scrolling so I can try to save and restore it, but I never find it (textview.getScrollX() always stay at 0 for example).

I also noticed that this "scrolling restart" also happen when I use the `textview.setVisibility(View.GONE); and textview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` methods.

Thanks for the help.